# Job triggering on code-checkin as well as at least once in a day if there is no code check in

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 multijob. MJ1  only does sync from GIT. MJ2 does the other activities like Deployment, DB creation, Test execution. Now I want the following:
i) MJ1 should be triggered every after 3 hrs if there is any code check in done.

ii) If there is no code check-in on a particular day or days then both of the MJ1 and MJ2 should run atleast once on that day/days.

Comment: Ok. So what approach have you tried so far?

Comment: First one approach is pretty simple and I can schedule the MJ1 and MJ2 both, every after 3 hrs in a day by providing the exact format in build periodically for 5 days in week. But then these jobs will run from Monday to Friday since code check in will be done on those days. But for weekend there will be no code check in but it should run atleast once. Is there any way to do it?